# Pulling Track Info From live stream Using PHP

Tags: php, streaming, live

I'm trying to pull out some tracks data from live radio stream

This is the stream address:
http://switch3.castup.net/cunet/gm.asp?ai=31&ar=88FM

I played a bit:

```
$streamingUrl = "http://switch3.castup.net/cunet/gm.asp?ai=31&ar=88FM";
$headers = get_headers($streamingUrl);
foreach ($headers as $h)
    echo $h . "<br>";

$stream = fopen($streamingUrl, 'r', false);
$buffer = stream_get_contents($stream, 1415);

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 11000; $i++)
{
    echo $buffer[$i];
}
```

Now, what I get is always a chunk of 1415 same bytes.
I want to be able to see the live bytes streaming and export out the current track name played.

Is there a way to do it with PHP ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get 1415 bytes of data, as that is the full length of the document you're fetching on that URL (try to get the contents of the document with `file_get_contents()` and echo it). In the document the actual stream URLs are defined, so you could parse those from the document and try to connect to those. However, those URLs suggest the Microsoft Media Server protocol is being used (indicated by the prefix mms://) you may be in for a bit more coding than 'open the connection and read the stream': you'll have to implement the [MMS protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234711.aspx) to get to the actual stream itself. And that'll be a whole new level of complexity.